# Google Classroom - link to meeting issue

Tags: google-chrome, chromebook, google-meet

I have a new Chromebook for my child's homeschool.  Whenever we join the class meeting using the icon at the top of google classroom, it opens in meet, not Chrome, which means she can't raise her hand or change the background, etc.

How do I change the setting so meetings always open in chrome instead of meet?

Comment: Have you contacted the school with this issue?

Comment: ^ This goes double if the school is managing the Chromebook. If that's the case, your options for troubleshooting are severely limited.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the meet app on your Chromebook.
To uninstall meet, click the launcher icon in your shelf, you should see an up arrow. After you click the up arrow, find the meet app, and right-click on it. Click uninstall and uninstall to confirm.